# Curiosity: Unassembled asm in Windows Bootloader

Tags: windows, debugging

I found this little gem waiting for me in the Windows (10/TP) bootmgr located on the first 300+- MB partition.

Can anyone explain to me what it does?
Is there an assembler hidden somewhere?
These all look like nicely null terminated strings to me...

```
DEBUG TRAP ^@^@** At linear address %lx
^@^@^@
 TRAP %lx ^@
 tr=%x  cr0=%lx  cr2=%lx  cr3=%lx
^@ gdt limit=%x  base=%lx    idt limit=%x  base=%lx
^@
 cs:eip=%x:%lx  ss:esp=%x:%lx  errcode=%x
^@ eax=%lx  ebx=%lx  ecx=%lx  edx=%lx^@ ds=%x  es=%x
^@ edi=%lx  esi=%lx  ebp=%lx  cr0=%lx^@ fs=%x  gs=%x
^@ flags=%lx  ^@Cy ^@NoCy ^@Zr ^@NoZr ^@IntEn^@IntDis ^@Up ^@Down ^@TrapEn 
^@TrapDis 
^@Link %x
^@Esp0 %x
^@SS0  %x
^@Esp1 %lx
^@Cr3  %lx
^@Eip  %lx
^@Eflg %lx
^@Eax  %lx
^@Ebx  %lx
^@Ecx  %lx
^@Edx  %lx
^@Esp  %lx
^@Ebp  %lx
^@Esi  %lx
^@Edi  %lx
^@ES   %x
^@CS   %x
^@SS   %x
^@DS   %x
^@FS   %x
^@GS   %x
^@Ldt  %x
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^G
```

Comment: That's not assembly, it's format strings for `printf()` that probably get used when something doesn't go right.

Comment: Could it be template for a boot-time error screen?  Something like a bood BSOD?

Comment: @Blrfl is probably right.  CTRL-@ is NUL, marking the end of a string constant.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. They sound mighty logical!